# How to connect two containers which are not part of same network

Tags: docker, docker-network

I have a scenario where I am starting my first container by sharing Unix socket. Due to the way our automation work, I can't alter the parameters of this docker run command.( eg: So I can't add a user-defined network )

```
docker run --rm -v /var/run/docker.sock:/var/run/docker.sock --entrypoint sh -it mytest:latest
```

Now from being within the mytest container, I am starting another container eg: nginx

```
/usr/bin/docker run --detach  --network host  --name test --publish "80:80" --publish "8080:80" nginx:latest
```

My requirement is I want to connect to nginx from mytest container. I tried to connect using `curl test:80` but it did not work. I tried to change --network to bridge but it did not work as well. I can use the host machine IP and access nginx but since the host machine IP changes frequently I can't hard code it as well.

Any suggestions on how to connect nginx from mytest container?

Comment: The solution is to use a user-created network. You'll want to fix your automation to work with docker.

Comment: Do you have access to the container name of the first container when running the second container command?

Comment: @hound, you issue look exactly the same which I faced few days ago and solved with community help, can you have a look at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61171399/application-running-in-docker-cant-connect-with-elasticsearch-docker and let me know if you have further questions

Answer (score 0):

Run your nginx container with `--network=host` and now you can connect to your first container by `localhost:exposed_public_port`

Comment: This doesn't work. ```curl localhost
curl: (7) Failed to connect to localhost port 80: Connection refused```

Comment: After run `docker run --network host nginx` (you don't have to publish ports when network is host) and ask for `localhost` I got response from nginx. Please update your question how you exactly run your containers and what url(s) you are asking.
Your first container has to expose and publish some port that you can connect to

Comment: I mentioned the exact command I am using. Like I said in my post, I cannot change the first container parameters since that is not my control. But I can change the second container run parameters. And I agree I don't have to publish the ports when I use --network host but it just shows a warning and command succeeds.

Comment: I read wrong your question. You want to connect from a first container (that you can't modify parameters) to the second one where you can do that. You should use `ip_your_host_machine:port_exposed_and_published_from_second_container`. Be sure that your firewall doesn't block that traffic. You can use docker "main" ip (is not specific container ip, is a ip of network your first container) instead of your host machine.

Comment: I mentioned that in my post that using host ip it works but i can't use host ip

Comment: I update my last answer and if doesn't work last try. Can you connect your second container to the network of first container?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/211304/discussion-between-hound-and-d0niek).