# Application running in docker can't connect with elasticsearch docker

Tags: java, amazon-web-services, docker, docker-compose, docker-network

I am new to docker and having a simple DW(dropwizard) application that connects to elasticsearch, Which is already running in docker using the docker-compose.yml, which has the following content.

**Docker-compose.yml for elasticsearch**

```
version: '2.2'

services:
  elasticsearch:
    image: docker.elastic.co/elasticsearch/elasticsearch:7.6.0
    container_name: elasticsearch
    environment:
      - xpack.security.enabled=false
      - discovery.type=single-node
    ports:
      - 8200:9200
      - 8300:9300

volumes:
  elasticsearch-data:
    driver: local
```

**Note: I am exposing 8200 and 8300 as ES port on my host(local mac system)**

Now everything works fine when I simply run my DW application which connects to ES in 8200 on localhost, **but now I am trying to dockerize my DW application and facing few issues.**

**Below is my Dockerfile for DW application**

```
COPY target/my.jar my.jar
COPY config.yml config.yml
ENTRYPOINT ["java" , "-jar" , "my.jar", "server", "config.yml"]
```

When I run my above DW docker image, it immediately stops, using `docker logs <my-container-id>`, it throws below exception:

```
*java.io.IOException: elasticsearch: Name does not resolve*
    org.elasticsearch.client.IndicesClient.exists(IndicesClient.java:827)
**Caused by: java.net.UnknownHostException: elasticsearch: Name does not resolve**
```

**Things I have tried**

1. The error message clearly mentions my DW app docker instance is not able to connect to elasticsearch, which I verified running fine.
2. Also checked the network of Elaticsearch docker and it has the network alias as `elasticsearch` as shown below and n/w as `docker-files_default`.

   "Aliases": [
                           "elasticsearch",
                           "de78c684ae60"
                       ],
3. Checked the n/w of my DW app docker instance and it uses `bridge` network and doesn't have any network alias.

**Now, how can I make both my app docker and elasticsearch docker use the same network so that they can connect with each other, I guess this would solve the issue?**

Comment: `EXPOSE` is only for documentation purpose, it does not publish anything. You should connect your containers to common network while running them and then the container name is the DNS name which you can use for intercontainer communication. (or just place them in one compose file and a default netowrk for your containers will be created automatically).

Comment: @michalk thanks for super quick response, is there is any other way to publish/bind container port to host ports? also for second part I am not very sure i want to do it as I am want to decouple them

Comment: @michalk, did you get a chance to look at my comment?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Two ways to solve this: First is to check what network docker-compose created for your elasticsearch setting (`docker network ls`) and then run your DW app with

`docker run --network=<name of network> ...`

Second way is to create a network `docker network create elastic` and use it as external network in your docker compose file as well as in your docker run command for the DW app.

Docker compose file could then look like

```
...
services:
  elasticsearch:
     networks:
       elastic:
...
networks:
    elastic:
        external: true
```

Comment: Hey, I already mentioned the name of network of elastic docker as well as DW app which I got using the same command, also I used your option 1 and it didn't work

Comment: and for second option, while creating `docker create network elastic` got `Error response from daemon: pull access denied for network, repository does not exist or may require 'docker login': denied: requested access to the resource is denied`, while other docker commands and pull working fine

Comment: Sorry I wrote the arguments in wrong order, it should be `docker network create elastic`. For the other way you would use `docker run --network=docker-files_default ...` so both containers share the same network

Comment: tried first option but still not able to make it work, didn't try the second option as it seems more work, also in case of the first option, confirmed both app and ES docker uses `docker-files_default` n/w and now error message is different and it throws `java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused` instead of initial `*java.io.IOException: elasticsearch: Name does not resolve*`

Comment: Sounds good so far. When using container network, use the internal ports, not the mapped ports. So for elastic: 9200