# Spring boot unable to connect to elasticsearch docker

Tags: java, spring-boot, docker, elasticsearch

My Elasticsearch docker-compose file is as such

```
version: '3'

services:
  elasticsearch:
    image: docker.elastic.co/elasticsearch/elasticsearch:6.8.6
    container_name: elasticsearch
    environment:
      - cluster.name=cluster
      - bootstrap.memory_lock=true
      - "ES_JAVA_OPTS=-Xms512m -Xmx512m"
    ulimits:
      memlock:
        soft: -1
        hard: -1
    volumes:
      - ./config/elasticsearch/elasticsearch.yml:/usr/share/elasticsearch/elasticsearch.yml
      - esdata6:/usr/share/elasticsearch/data    
    ports:
      - "9200:9200"
  kibana:
    image: docker.elastic.co/kibana/kibana:6.8.6
    container_name: kibana
    volumes:
      - ./config/kibana/kibana.yml:/usr/share/kibana/kibana.yml
    restart: on-failure
    ports:
      - "5601:5601"

volumes:
  esdata6:
```

I have a spring boot application and the application.properties is

```
spring.data.elasticsearch.repositories.enabled=true
spring.data.elasticsearch.cluster-nodes=localhost:9200
spring.data.elasticsearch.cluster-name=cluster
```

However, I am getting the error

```
2020-04-18 13:49:45.775  INFO 7576 --- [           main] o.s.d.e.c.TransportClientFactoryBean     : Adding transport node : 127.0.0.1:9200
2020-04-18 13:50:16.961 ERROR 7576 --- [           main] .d.e.r.s.AbstractElasticsearchRepository : failed to load elasticsearch nodes : org.elasticsearch.client.transport.NoNodeAvailableException: None of the configured nodes are available: [{#transport#-1}{Lzoi5ddvSJizvu4g3Y3E6Q}{localhost}{127.0.0.1:9200}]
```

Question: 
1) How can i connect to the elasticsearch with spring boot externally?
2) If I docker-compose up the elastic and the springboot application together, they would be on the same network. What change should I ammend to spring.data.elasticsearch.cluster-nodes in order to connect to the elastic search?

I am using spring-boot-starter-data-elasticsearch in the spring boot app.

Comment: this post might help you https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61171399/application-running-in-docker-cant-connect-with-elasticsearch-docker , please comment if you have similar requirements or need further info

Comment: My spring boot app in a docker-compose file and my es docker-compose file are in the same directory, therefore they are on the same docker network. The spring boot app should be able to access the elasticsearch via the service name. Anyway i tried your suggestion in the link as well but it still does not connect. It says unknown host

Comment: can you use `docker inpsect container-id` for both the spring app and es docker container and in output check the network section for both and paste here ?

Answer (score 0):

In your application.properties file spring.data.elasticsearch.cluster-nodes should be **elasticsearch:9200** rather than **localhost:9200.**

Answer (score 0):

This is almost similar to the issue which I faced a few days back and also mentioned in [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61171399/application-running-in-docker-cant-connect-with-elasticsearch-docker) SO question, but Let me explain here as there are some similar caveats in your use case that I solved.

Using the docker inspect container-id checked the network used by my elasticsearch docker container, part of which looks like below:

```
"Networks": {
            "docker-files_default": {->this is network name used by elasticsearch docker.
                "IPAMConfig": null,
                "Links": null,
                "Aliases": [
                    "elasticsearch",
                    "de78c684ae60"
                ],
```

Now defined my docker-compose for my app as below:

```
version: '3'
services:
  web:
    build: .
    ports:
      - "8080:8080"
    volumes:
      - .:/code
    networks: --> see it uses the network section and below which defines the same network used by elastic docker 
      - docker-files_default

networks:  --> note this section as well, you need to add this as well.
  docker-files_default:
    external: true
```

**After this, as both docker containers are using the same network, you can use the name of your elasticsearch docker container name, which is elasticsearch as shown in your elastic docker-compose.yml.** So below spring config for elastic would be:

```
spring.data.elasticsearch.cluster-nodes=elasticsearch:9200
```